# ASP.NET Cross Domain Web Service & Session State

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, cross-domain

Here's a really loaded question. I would like to implement a shared page using ASP.NET that I can download from a Web Service to include in an ASP, ASP.NET, or PHP page on any domain. The shared page would be hosted on a separate server on a different domain, so I do not have access to the typical ASP.NET Page Methods.

Also, I would need to be able to use jQuery to send AJAX GET and POST requests to the Web Service, and be able to preserve the session state.

Is such an implementation possible in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect cookies to transit domains. Anything that you try to do in this regard with cookies is likely to be prevented by the security in the web-browser.

Also, there are a number of caveats to attempting cross-domain AJAX requests. See [AJAX - Introducing Cross-domain Request (XDR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [Getting a cross-domain JSON with jQuery in Internet Explorer 8 and newer versions](http://graphicmaniacs.com/note/getting-a-cross-domain-json-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8-and-later/), and [Ticket #8283 Built-in support for XDomainRequest](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283).

You may want to consider one of the following alternatives:

- Put your web service on the same site.
- Have the site make the query to the web service on behalf of the user.

Comment: What if I made a "proxy" page that takes an AJAX request and forwards it to the web service, and then returns whatever the web service returns in its response? Would that work?

Comment: Yes. that would be an implementation of the second alternative and can be made to work. You can actually make cross-domain requests from the browser work as well, but as you can see from the links that I provided, it's complicated.

Comment: Someone seems to have already created a proxy web service for cross-domain requests: http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-create-simple-proxy-in-aspnet.html

Comment: I gave it a look and I agree that it seems promising.